# Google Apps Script menus are not appearing in a shared spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I create a spreadsheet with a Google App Script. I shared it with other person, but the customized menus (created with the `onOpen`trigger) that are normally shown in my google spreadsheet aren't shown in the shared spreadsheet. The script uses folders to put the created docs and folders with templates, and I also shared both. What can be producing this?

EDIT: After @Sergeinsas sugestion, I added this line of code: `ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnOpen").forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onOpen().create();` (where `ss` is a global variable `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`
). After, I call my new trigger:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function installedOnOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [
                     {name: My function menu name", functionName: "someFunction"}
                    ];
  ss.addMenu("My personalized menu", menuEntries);   

}
```

But it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: Are you using a simple onOpen or an installable one?

Comment: a simple onOpen. The spreadsheet is the same (it works to me, but not to the other people)

Comment: It happens to me quite often, I don't have any good explanation...so I simply use an installable trigger that always work. I even keep the same same sometime (I know I shouldn't :-) but it has no side effect, it's only a menu after all!

Comment: I, @Sergeinsas, did you mean " I even keep the same name..."? =)

Comment: Yes... the same function name:  onOpen()  did I say something funny without noticing it?

Comment: You said "the same same" (and I'm not an English speaker =). Shouldn't  this issue be noticed to Google?

Comment: Is the spreadsheet being shared with editor permissions? As far as I know you need that to see the custom menu entries.

Comment: I experienced the same thing. Using an installable onOpen trigger fixed it for me too.

Comment: This issue occurred to me but only when adding multiple menu items from different scripts. I was able to resolve it when I consolidated all menu items insertion to the same "onOpen" method, even though the referred functions are spread across different code files.